# Django ListView filtro

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Estoy haciendo una proyecto donde tengo un ListView para listar datos en una tabla de mi modelo Inventory, tengo un solo modelo que es como un inventario de equipos de diferentes paises. Estoy tratando de mostrar en diferentes ListView con su template y muestre en pantalla el hostname pero con el acrónimo que le corresponde, por ej: España tiene el acrónimo PESSOL y Colombia el PCOSOL, entonces quiero mostrar que cuando pinche el inventario de España solo me liste en la tabla los que tienen el PESSOL y cuando pinche el de Colombia los de PCOSOL.

He estado tratando de hacerlo con un get_queryset o con un get_context_data pero nada, no se si  pueda hacer un filtrado en el mismo template de ese atributo hostname.

muestro algunas imágenes para que entiendas mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Inventory(models.Model):

LAPTOPS='0'
DESKTOP='1'
SURFACE='2'

MODEL_TEAM=[
    (LAPTOPS,'Laptops'),
    (DESKTOP,'Desktop'),
    (SURFACE,'Surface'),

]


location = models.CharField('Location', max_length=100)
direction = models.CharField('Direction', max_length=150)
hostname = models.CharField('Hostanme', max_length=50)
nuuma = models.CharField('Nuuma', max_length=70)
serial_number = models.CharField('Serial number', max_length=50)
product_number = models.CharField('Product number', max_length=50,blank= True)
mac_address= models.CharField('MAC',max_length=50)
mac_wifi = models.CharField('MAC WIFI', max_length=50, blank=True)
manufacturer = models.CharField('Manufacturer', max_length=50)
name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=1, choices=MODEL_TEAM)
observations= models.CharField('Observations', max_length=70)
```

Se que una forma fácil de hacerlo es repitiendo el mismo modelo Inventory varias veces en el models.py y asociar cada modelo a las vistas pero pienso que repetiría el mismo código varias veces el models.py y no lo veo eficiente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tener varios `ListView` para cada acronimo, no es en lo absoluto optimo, hasta se repite código.

Yo planteo esta forma mas optima donde solo es necesario un `ListView`:

```
class InventoryListView(ListView):
    model = Inventory
    template_name = '...'

    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('acronym') is not None:
            return Inventory.objects.filter(
                hostname__startswith = self.request.GET['acronym']
            )

        return super().get_queryset()
```

La vista filtra los equipos, donde el valor del campo `hostname` empiece con el valor del parámetro HTTP GET `acronym` esperado, si dicho parámetro HTTP GET no es enviado simplemente listara TODOS los equipos sin discriminar.

Si el acronimo no es correcto o es texto al azar, simplemente **no habrá coincidencias en la búsqueda** dando como resultado un QuerySet vació, que se reflejara en el template.

Por otra parte la "búsqueda de campo" [`startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#startswith) funciona buscando coincidencias al principio de la cadena o valor del campo.

Ahora, las URLs en tu HTML deberían ser así:

```
<a href="{% url '...' %}?acronym=PCOSOL">Iventory Colombia</a>
<a href="{% url '...' %}?acronym=PESSOL">Iventory España</a>
```

De ahí, la vista se encargara y no es necesario tener varias vistas `ListView` para cada acronimo. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Colocando un queryset con `__icontains`.

Le indicas que quieres que vaya y recupere en el hostname todo lo que contenga esa parte ya que cada codigo es diferente solo colocas  PESSOL para españa y PCOSOL para colombia que es lo que nunca cambia

[image: get_queryset]